# I can't exit my program

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a command interpretor like bash and I have a little problem.

When i execute existing commands like ls/cat/grep it works without problem , but when I try to execute command like qsdjhkoqd, it would say command not found, and if I try to exit after it, it won't exit.

For exemple if I do 4 bad comments, i will have to do 5 exits to quit my program.
I know it's certainly a processus problem but I don't know how to fix it, could you tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks !

```
int im_your_father(t_struct *tool, char **env, char **argv)
{
  int   ret;

  ret = 0;
  if (tool->command.pid == 0)
    {
      ret = execve(tool->command.command, argv, env);
    }
  else
    wait(NULL);
  return (ret);
}

int execute_path(t_struct *tool , char **env , 
             char **argv, t_first_elem *list)
{
  int   i;
  int   ret;

  tool->command.pid = fork();
  (void)list;
  i = -1;
  if (my_strcmp("ls", argv[0]) == 0)
    {
      while (argv[++i] != NULL)
    ;
      argv[i] = my_strdup("--color=auto");
      argv[++i] = NULL;
      i = -1;
    }
  while (tool->path[++i] != NULL)
    { 
      tool->command.command = my_strdup_mod(tool->path[i], 
                        my_strlen(tool->command.line));
      my_strcat(tool->command.command, "/");
      my_strcat(tool->command.command, argv[0]);
      ret = im_your_father(tool, env, argv);
      if (ret != -1)
    return (0);
    }
  if (tool->command.pid == 0)
    {
      my_putstr("son alive");
    }
  else
    {
      printf("%d\n", tool->command.pid);
      wait(NULL);
    }
  my_putstr(argv[0]);
  my_putstr(":   command not found\n");
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is mostly in these lines:

```
if (tool->command.pid == 0)
{
    ret = execve(tool->command.command, argv, env);
}
```

First of all, there's no need to capture the return value from `execve()`.  If it is successful, it never returns; if it returns at all, it failed.

Secondly, you need to consider what happens next, and the short answer is that you now have two processes, both of which think they're your shell.  You now have two processes trying to read your input, and they squabble over who gets each character, and the result is a mess, just like when human children are squabbling over whose turn it is to use a favoured toy.

Most of the time, especially in a shell, if the `execve()` fails, you are going to want to exit, possibly after producing an error message:

```
if (tool->command.pid == 0)
{
    execve(tool->command.command, argv, env);
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute %s (%s)\n", tool->command.command, strerror(errno));
    exit(127);
}
```

The exact exit status is negotiable; I usually just use `1`, but the POSIX standard does stipulate [exit statuses](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02) when failing to execute a command:

> If a command is not found, the exit status shall be 127. If the command name is found, but it is not an executable utility, the exit status shall be 126.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now i don't know why I don't thought to exit after my execve call.